# C++ threading to download

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need help with C++ threading stuff, I have created a dll which has a exported function as downloadfile (to download a file from the internet). This function in turns create a thread to download a file (the function used to download a file is blocking function i.e. URLDownloadToFile that's why I put the download functionality on thread).

I want to achieve following.

1. my call to downloadfile function should not block the main thread.
2. I want to download more than one file at a time.

remember that, download functionality is in the dll created in C++ and this dll will be used in Pascal.

following is the code snippet:

```
struct DOWNLOADPARAM
{
    HANDLE hEventStop;
    TCHAR *szURL;
    TCHAR *szFilePath;
};


DWORD WINAPI Transfer(void *hw)
{
    Mutex mutex_;

    DOWNLOADPARAM *const pDownloadParam = static_cast<DOWNLOADPARAM *>(hw);
    CBSCallbackImpl bsc(NULL, pDownloadParam->hEventStop);


           const HRESULT hr = ::URLDownloadToFile(NULL,pDownloadParam->szURL  ,pDownloadParam->szFilePath,0,&bsc);


    return 0;
}


extern "C" void  __declspec(dllexport)   downloadfile(TCHAR *url, TCHAR *dest)
{
    Mutex mutex_;

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    DOWNLOADPARAM *obj = new DOWNLOADPARAM();
    obj->szURL      = url;
    obj->szFilePath = dest;


    if((hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Transfer, (LPVOID)obj, 0,&dwThreadId)) != NULL)
    {
    }


// Following code block the thread untill finished 

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Comment: You should explain what problem you have with this.

Comment: You should also explain what you are doing with those `Mutex`es. I see you declaring them, but I don't see you using them.

Comment: As i mentioned I want to actually call the dll downloadfile function from inno script (pascal scripting). inno doesn't support threads or timers or waiting functions thats why I am creating a new dll file which will download the files from the internet async. I need more information/help on this.

Comment: I assume something about the code you have isn't working as you would expect? So what happens when you use the dll? What is going wrong? What doesn't work about it? If there are bugs in your code that you want to get tracked down, you have to tell us how they show up/...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `downloadFile` function is waiting for the download thread to finish before it returns, which will cause it to block just like the `URLDownloadToFile` function does. I would suggest that you break this apart into two operations; `downloadFile` should return some sort of handle or event that the calling program can use to determine whether the operation has completed, and then when it has, provide a second function that cleans up the thread and handles. That way, the calling program can continue to run and use a WaitForMultipleObjects or some other mechanism to allow it to perform its own processing while still being notified when the download has completed. My Win32 is sketchy at best, so I can't really draft up some example code, but I hope the design idea is helpful.

Comment: thanks the idea is really helpful, but as i mentioned I want to actually call the dll downloadfile function from inno script (pascal scripting). inno doesn't support threads or timers or waiting functions thats why I am creating a new dll file which will download the files from the internet async. I need more information on this...

Comment: In that case, you could use a variable in the DLL to keep track of when the operation has completed, and poll to see when it goes true. It's a little crude, you might have to synchronize access to it, and you'll have to be careful that the same variable doesn't get shared if you do two downloads at once or run the program twice at once, but it should work.

Comment: the code is working perfectly, The problem I have with this dll code is that If I remove the wait function (waitforsingleobject) from the dll to make this call as async, then download doesn't work as the thread exit as I am calling this dll function from Inno script. how i implement the wait without blocking the call. or is there is any other way I can download internet file async.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `WaitForSingleObject` on thread handle immediately after launching the thread is nothing more than a synchronous/blocking call. You should defer `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: Actually the timer has to be implemented into the Inno script which call the dll's downloadfile function. but unfortunately inno script doesn't support theads and timers..so thats why I have coded the c++ dll to achieve this. but the download file from the internet is sync calls and doesn't solve the purpose. the call should be async. so that I can download the file at the background thread in the dll and as well work on the inno script installer UI.